# Adding custom login to OpenId/Federated Login on Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid

Currently have an client application running on GAE that supports OpenId login to access resources on a server application (also on GAE) through OAuth.  All is fine.

But, it requires that the user have an account with Google, Yahoo, or other OpenId provider.  While that seems fine for personal users, how do I handle the corporate case where users want to use myname@mycompany.com as their login?

Do I build my own OpenId provider, host it, and store those names/passwords in a database?
Is there existing OpenId source that I can use, but give it my own names/passwords?
Do I skip OpenId entirely and somehow get my own custom db lookup to integrate with GAE authentication?
Something complete different?

My work is in Java, so Java solutions are preferred.  And since this is more for prototyping than for production use, easier solutions are preferred :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional research it seems that if I want to stick with my current use of Restlet's GAEAuthenticator then I will have to rely on OpenId.  There appears to be ways to rewrite the entire authentication so that it works both with Google/OpenId and a custom database (not what I want to try), and there appear to be commercial products (SadaSystems) that seem to also do it.
For now, my workaround is to ask people who want to use their own email address in our system to sign up with MyOpenId and add that email address as their persona.